# javaFX event listener

Tags: javafx

[image]

When the user selects one of the watches from the product table, change the *Selected Watch* label according to the selected watch’s name.

How to create this?

```java
public void setTable() {
    TableColumn<Product, Integer> watchIdColumn = new TableColumn<Product, Integer>("Watch ID"); 
    TableColumn<Product, String> watchNameColumn = new TableColumn<Product, String>("Watch Name"); 
    TableColumn<Product, String> watchBrandColumn = new TableColumn<Product, String>("Watch Brand"); 
    TableColumn<Product, String> watchPriceColumn = new TableColumn<Product, String>("Watch Price");
    TableColumn<Product, Integer> watchStockColumn = new TableColumn<Product, Integer>("Watch Stock");
        
    watchIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Integer>("watchID"));
    watchNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("watchName"));
    watchBrandColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("watchBrand"));
    watchPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("watchPrice"));
    watchStockColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Integer>("watchStock"));

    tableProduct.getColumns().addAll(watchIdColumn, watchNameColumn, watchBrandColumn, watchPriceColumn, watchStockColumn);
    tableProduct.getItems().add(new Product(1,"Submariner 300 Watch","Rolex", "$10500", 4));
    tableProduct.getItems().add(new Product(2,"Sea Master Planet Ocean Watch","Omega", "$6900", 5));
```

Comment: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html

Comment: Observe the selected item property of the table's selection model.

Answer (score 4):

Add a listener to the [selectedItemProperty](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedItemProperty) of the `TableView`'s [selection model](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.TableViewSelectionModel.html). Below code demonstrates. (More notes after the code.)

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView.TableViewSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ProdTabl extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TableView<Product> tableProduct = new TableView<>();
        ObservableList<Product> items = tableProduct.getItems();
        Product p = new Product(1,
                                "Submariner 300 Watch",
                                "Rolex",
                                new BigDecimal("10500"),
                                4);
        items.add(p);
        p = new Product(2,
                        "Sea Master Planet Ocean Watch",
                        "Omega",
                        new BigDecimal("6900"),
                        5);
        items.add(p);

        TableColumn<Product, Number> watchIdColumn = new TableColumn<>("Watch ID");
        watchIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().watchIDProperty());

        TableColumn<Product, String> watchNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Watch Name");
        watchNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().watchNameProperty());

        TableColumn<Product, String> watchBrandColumn = new TableColumn<>("Watch Brand");
        watchBrandColumn.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().watchBrandProperty());

        TableColumn<Product, BigDecimal> watchPriceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Watch Price");
        watchPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().watchPriceProperty());

        TableColumn<Product, Number> watchStockColumn = new TableColumn<>("Watch Stock");
        watchStockColumn.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().watchStockProperty());

        ObservableList<TableColumn<Product, ?>> columns = tableProduct.getColumns();
        columns.add(watchIdColumn);
        columns.add(watchNameColumn);
        columns.add(watchBrandColumn);
        columns.add(watchPriceColumn);
        columns.add(watchStockColumn);

        Label label = new Label("Selected Watch: ");

        TableViewSelectionModel<Product> selectionModel = tableProduct.getSelectionModel();
        ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Product> sip = selectionModel.selectedItemProperty();
        sip.addListener((v, o, n) -> label.setText("Selected Watch: " +
                                                             (n == null ? "" : n.getWatchName())));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(tableProduct);
        root.setTop(label);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(label, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        BorderPane.setMargin(label, new Insets(10.0));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}

class Product {
    private SimpleIntegerProperty  watchID;
    private SimpleStringProperty  watchName;
    private SimpleStringProperty  watchBrand;
    private SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal>  watchPrice;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty  watchStock;

    public Product(int id, String name, String brand, BigDecimal price, int stock) {
        watchID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "watchID", id);
        watchName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "watchName", name);
        watchBrand = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "watchBrand", brand);
        watchPrice = new SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal>(this, "watchPrice", price);
        watchStock = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "watchStock", stock);
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty watchIDProperty() {
        return watchID;
    }

    public int getWatchID() {
        return watchID.get();
    }

    public void setWatchID(int id) {
        watchID.set(id);
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty watchNameProperty() {
        return watchName;
    }

    public String getWatchName() {
        return watchName.get();
    }

    public void setWatchName(String name) {
        watchName.set(name);
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty watchBrandProperty() {
        return watchBrand;
    }

    public String getWatchBrand() {
        return watchBrand.get();
    }

    public void setWatchBrand(String brand) {
        watchBrand.set(brand);
    }

    public SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal> watchPriceProperty() {
        return watchPrice;
    }

    public BigDecimal getWatchPrice() {
        return watchPrice.get();
    }

    public void setWatchPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        watchPrice.set(price);
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty watchStockProperty() {
        return watchStock;
    }

    public int getWatchStock() {
        return watchStock.get();
    }

    public void setWatchStock(int stock) {
        watchStock.set(stock);
    }
}
```

- It is recommended **not** to use `PropertyValueFactory` class.
- The properties of class `Product` do not have to be [ObservableValue](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.base/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html)s but I think it's better if they are. For one thing, it simplifies the *cell value factory* code.
- The `setCellValueFactory` method parameter is a [Callback](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.base/javafx/util/Callback.html). This is an interface with a single method, `call`, which takes a single, generic parameter and returns a generic value. Hence the interface can be implemented via a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).
- In the case of your `TableColumn` the actual type of the [`call`] method parameter is [CellDataFeatures](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.CellDataFeatures.html). The JavaFX infrastructure will call this method and pass an appropriate instance of `CellDataFeatures`. All you need to do is return an appropriate value.
- It is recommended to use class `BigDecimal` when dealing with money. However, if the [watch] price is merely for show, then you can keep it as `String`.
- Java 7 introduced the [diamond operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html).
- The parameters for the `selectedItemProperty` listener are:

  1. `v` - the property itself
  2. `o` - the previous value of the property
  3. `n` - the current value of the property
- Both `o` and `n` are instances of class `Product`.

Here is a screen capture:

[image: screen capture]